# Look for substring in string to find part before searched sentence

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, substring

In:

```
 string str = "On the screen the faint, old, robed figure of Mercer toiled upward, and all at once a rock sailed past him.";
```

search for sub-string:

```
 string find = "figure of";
```

if this way:

```
 string reg = string.Format("({0} +([\\w+]+))", find);
 var result = new Regex(reg).Match(str);
```

I can get part followed to searched sentence:

```
figure of Mercer
```

But how to find part of phrase before searched sentence:

```
 On the screen the faint, old, robed
```

And get only nearest word:

```
 robed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) will help to find starting index of [`Substing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string str = "On the screen the faint, old, robed figure of Mercer toiled upward, and all at once a rock sailed past him.";
string find = "figure of";

var index = str.IndexOf(find);

if (index >= 0)
{
    var result = str.Substring(0, index);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes and how do you get only first word? I've edited question

Comment: If you have the index of what you are looking for, string.Substring (possibly combined with a string.Length or two) will let you find any chunk of what you are looking at - relative to what you originally found.